# Editing registry keys in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am trying to create a registry key value in windows to run my program at login here's what I've tried:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <WinReg.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"Advapi32.lib")
using namespace std;
int main () {
    HKEY hKey;          
    DWORD buffersize = 4;
    DWORD data = 3;

    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, &hKey)) 
    { 
        if (RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"test", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(data)))
        { 
            RegCloseKey (hKey); 
            return FALSE; 
        }

        RegCloseKey (hKey); 
    } 
}
```

This doesn't seem to be creating the value even when run as admin, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: doesn't work? Does your code return any error codes? Are you using a 32-bit process? Have you checked the 32-bit registry?

Comment: Make sure you read about the [Registry Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector). The key may have been created, but not in the place you are looking. Also, there doesn't appear to be a striking reason to change the HKLM hive instead of HKCU.

Comment: Did you mean to pass `REG_DWORD` instead of `REG_SZ`?

Comment: Hi, have you solve this issue? And is there the answer available for you? Please feel free to mark it, or add your answer then mark yourself to help people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use `RegCreateKeyEx` when writing, the key might not be there.

2) You are writing DWORD data but storing it as a string, the call will succeeded but it is basically corrupted data.

```
WCHAR buf[] = L"foo bar";
RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"a string", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)buf, sizeof(buf)));

DWORD num = 42;
RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"a DWORD", 0, REG_WORD, (LPBYTE)&num, sizeof(num)));
```

3) 32-bit processes on 64-bit Windows writes to a different area, in Regedit you must look under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. Use `KEY_SET_VALUE|KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to access the 64-bit key in a 32-bit app.